# To one digit calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please help me in excel to find functions in the result cell following by calculation.

```
ID     Result  Calculation  
12345  6       >>1+2+3+4+5=15   >>1+5   =6  
21436  6       >>2x1x4x3x6=144  >>1x4x4 = 16 >>1x6  =6  
12345  2       >>1x2x3x4x5=120  >>1x2   =2    Omit zero digit
```

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question, please? What do you need?

Answer (score 1):

First if you don't want some horribly complex code you need to put it in a macro.
If you tried to put it in 1 cell it would probably be over 200 characters long and impossible to debug.

Something like this:

```
assuming var "in" contains the string

accumulator=0
for a=1 to len(in)
accumulator=accumulator*value(mid(trim(in),a,1))
next a

sum=0
while accumulator>9
for b=0 to len(accumulator)
sum=sum*value(mid(trim(accumulator),a,1))
next b
accumulator=sum
sum=0
wend
```

**Note:**  You switch from multiply to add based on unknown criteria so I was unable to code for that.

Comment: There's a simple trick for a short formula for addition but I don't know a shortcut for multiplication - you were close - my version hits 189 characters!

Answer (score 0):

For addition, as per line 1 you can reduce to a single digit like this:

`=MOD(A2-1,9)+1`

but you also want to do the same for multiplication? As cybernard says, I don't see how you are determining which to use so for a separate multiplication formula, assuming 3 iterations at most and up to 10 digits in the original try this formula

`=PRODUCT(SUBSTITUTE((0&MID(PRODUCT(SUBSTITUTE((0&MID(PRODUCT(SUBSTITUTE((0&MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:10")),1))+0,0,1)+0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:10")),1))+0,0,1)+0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:10")),1))+0,0,1)+0)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>